# Chrome emulator clear cache

Tags: flutter, google-chrome

I know there is a way to clear Gbs of cache on android studio emulator
But is there a way to clear the chrome web emulator cache because the storage it used doesn't come back after I close the flutter ptoject on vscode.

Please help because I'm even contemplating uninstalling flutter.

Answer (score 4):

To clear the cache/ any other storage that you have in an application you can do the following:

1. Open up the inspector in chrome (mac: cmd + option + c) (windows: ctrl + shift + c)
2. Click on `application` in the top bar in the inspector
3. Click on `storage` in the sidebar
4. Click on `Clear site data`

You can also manage the individual pieces of information stored in your app in the other storage tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear cache in google chrome

windows  `ctrl + shift + R`

Mac `Command + Shift + R`